Save field value After Complete Order
I am using Craft Commerce and want to edit the order after it has been completed by the customer. For this I am using the EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER event.
Event::on(
            Order::class,
            Order::EVENT_AFTER_COMPLETE_ORDER,
            function (Event $event) {
                $order = $event->sender;
                $order = Order::find()->id($order->id)->one();

                if (!$order) {
                    throw new \Exception('Invalid order ID: ' . $this->id);
                }

                if ($order->shippingMethodHandle === 'DHL' && !$order->parcelNumber) {
                    $order->setFieldValue("parcelNumber", 5005);

                    if (!Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($order)) {
                        Craft::error('Automatic creation of Mikropakket label has failed.', __METHOD__);
                    }
                }
            }
        );

I can correctly read the values in the $order variable but saving the parcelNumber does not seem to work. There are no errors and when I debug with Xdebug I can see that the saveElement method is being called.
When looking at the order the parcelNumber field is empty.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

It seems that the following line was not needed.
$order = Order::find()->id($order->id)->one();
When I removed it everything works as expected.
